# Handling checkbox event in option menu : Android

Tags: android, checkbox, menu

I have a menu that has checkbox menu item type and whenever i check it. It doesn't trigger anything. Here is my menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/delete"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.CheckBox"
    android:checkableBehavior="single"
    android:title="All"
    android:titleCondensed="All"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"></item>
</menu>
```

Here is my **onOptionsItemSelected**

```
  @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.delete:
            Toast.makeText(this,"Hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can handle CheckBox click inside `onCreateOptionsMenu` by listen `setOnCheckedChangeListener` like this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) menu.findItem(R.id.delete).getActionView();
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                // perform logic
            }
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

And remember change `android:actionViewClass="android.widget.CheckBox"` to `app:actionViewClass="android.widget.CheckBox"`

Comment: Seems while setting `OnCheckedChangeListener` object `checkBox` was null
Giving : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: It works man, thanks. And do you have any idea how to change the back button of contextual action bar into check box? Like when you long pressed the listview it will show a select all checkbox.

Comment: @shadygoneinsane thank you for correct me, please check my answer again

Comment: @Meowok I think it is a different question, you should add new question. And if you think my answer solve your problem please mark it as correct answer. Thank you